# Browse or mount SD card over WiFi on Linux?

Tags: sd-card, linux, file-transfer, file-management

Is there a way to browse the contents of my SD card from my Linux (Ubuntu 10.04) machine over WiFi?

I used to connect with a mini-usb cable, or send files through gmail. Surely there must be a way to access the files through wifi.

My main focus is ease-of-use, I don't particularly care about speed or security. Although I do prefer a non-cloud solution due to privacy concerns.

(I have not actively searched for a solution yet. I will do this now, so maybe I will answer my own question. Which, as I understood from Atwood, is proper use of a StackExchange site.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use FTPServer ( http://www.appbrain.com/app/ftpserver/lutey.FTPServer ) to browse and copy files to and from my phone over wifi. On Ubuntu you can connect to an FTP server and browse it as if it is a directory.

Comment: That's indeed the easiest I think. (Although I'm using SwiFTP now.)

Answer (score 4):

**WiFi File Explorer** allows browsing of the SD card through a web based interface. Quite nice, but perhaps difficult to copy a large number of files.

http://lifehacker.com/5626268/wifi-file-explorer-manages-your-android-sd-card-from-a-web-browser

**On Air (Wifi Disk)** 'allows you to easily transfer files over your Wi-Fi connection by accessing it as if it were a drive', but only for Mac I suppose.

**SwiFTP** is an FTP server, which does what it says.

Answer (score 0):

There is [WiFi FTP Server](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.medhaapps.wififtpserver&hl=en_CA) from Google Play store which I plan to download and chronicle setup. It has many positive reviews (4.4 stars out of 5 stars) and 500K+ Downloads.

There is a free version with ads and a paid version that is only $0.99 which is a small price to pay to support the developers (IMHO).

My goal is to have static IP address for phone on Home WiFi network and Ubuntu's `cron` run a job every morning to `mount` external storage card, log last access time for 3600 filenames and then `umount` external storage card.

Comment: Are you promoting that app or fell prey to rating? It contains [trackers](https://reports.exodus-privacy.eu.org/en/reports/78127/) , why not always free and ad-free [MiXplorer](https://mixplorer.com/) or open-source [SwiFTP](https://github.com/ppareit/swiftp)? Personally I use [pure-ftpd](https://github.com/jedisct1/pure-ftpd). Btw Android mounts `/data` as well as (emulated) `/sdcard` with `noatime`.

Comment: @IrfanLatif It turns out the package is no good for mounting in Linux because you need to use `sshfs` as per my answer here: [How to mount Android external storage over WiFi instead of USB](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1178818/how-to-mount-android-external-storage-over-wifi-instead-of-usb). The atime is displayed (but incorrect because of `noatime` in `/etc/fstab`) whereas in Nautilus WiFi FTTP Server shows "Unknown" for atime. The GUI Nautilus does me no good I needed to fuse mount it so I could use CLI commands. Also, FTP has security flaws. SSH is the way to go I think.

Comment: SSHFS? That's for SFTP, not FTP if I'm not mistaken. To be able to see Last Access Time is of no use when the original file doesn't have relevant time stamp at all. Yes SSH is far better than FTP, that's why I went [that far](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/209918). I have both SSH and FTP servers running on my device as native service when I turn on WiFi. FTP is chrooted to `/sdcard/FTP` where I put files that I want to share over WLAN. Other party can access the files even in a web browser, that's the only benefit of FTP.

Comment: @IrfanLatif +1 to Q&A. It's a valuable resource.