# How can I transfer files from PC to Phone or vice versa without internet

Tags: file-transfer

I am using a cloud service (Dropbox) when I am using internet for file transfer. But how can I transfer files between my PC and my Android device without going via the Internet? and of course without using data cable.

Comment: related: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4100/browse-or-mount-sd-card-over-wifi-on-linux

Comment: If the PC and the phone are in the same network, you can use Locally App (https://www.locally1.com). You can still use the app if you can create hotspot on your phone and connect the pc to it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are multiple solutions available:

### Using an USB Cable

If you connect your device to your PC via an USB cable, it shares (parts of) its storage to the PC. With versions prior to Android 4.x your device usually identifies as [USB storage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_storage) (like any external disk/USB-stick attached), never Android versions might use [MTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_Transfer_Protocol) instead, which might require special drivers on your PC to be used.

Once connected, you can transfer files easily between PC and Android device.

### Using a card reader

If your device features a slot for sd cards, you could simply remove the sd card from your device (remember to unmount it first via the device's setup menu), put it into a card reader, and attach it to the PC. It should then pop-up on your PC as "USB storage" as described above.

### Wireless solutions (Browser-based)

There are a bunch of wireless solutions available -- and this is not the place to list them all. Principially, you can install any FTP/Web server, and configure it to offer the directories you wish to access.

As this might be too complicated for many users, there are quite easy solutions. The probably most well-known is [AirDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid), which offers a nice interface to manage almost your entire device from your PC:

[image: Airdroid]

As the example screenshot shows, a file browser is included -- and permits you to upload and download files to/from your device.

A second example for an easy-to-use app would be [WiFi File Transfer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.smarterdroid.wififiletransfer), which -- as the name suggests -- is specialized to transfer files via WiFi:

[image: WiFi File Transfer]

There are many more possibilities, just check the playstore. A good starting point are the playstore pages of the mentioned two examples, then lookup related apps.

### Other Wireless Solutions

There are many more wireless solutions available. As Logos mentioned it in his comment, I will add some examples here for completeness:

#### Samba

You can use apps like [Samba Filesharing](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.funkyfresh.samba) to turn your Android device into a [Samba](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samba_%28software%29) server. In short, Samba (or SMB, or [CIFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cifs)) is the protocol used by Windows shares. Linux also understands this protocol. Using Samba, one thus can access the Android device's file system (without root, this will be restricted to the internal/external sd card) like any Samba-/Windows share.

#### WebDAV

Several apps like e.g. [DavDrive](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.fun2code.android.lite.webdrive) can share the Android device's storage via the [WebDAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webdav) protocol. This works via HTTP, but can also be accessed like a "shared drive" using the appropriate software on the PC.

#### Bluetooth

Don't forget that we also have this available -- at least on our Android devices. But also keep in mind this is much slower than WiFi. Nevertheless, it can be facilitated using apps like [Bluetooth File Transfer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=it.medieval.blueftp).

#### FTP

The [File Transfer Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FTP) also is an option. There are several apps available turning an Android device into an [FTPServer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=lutey.FTPServer)...

#### Other solutions

For completeness, let's just name them in short: SSH Server, Web server, File Synchronization tools (like e.g. [FolderSync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dk.tacit.android.foldersync.lite)), and probably several other options I'm currently unaware of...

Comment: If you know networking at all, in my opinion for simple filesharing using a small app Samba can't be beat: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.funkyfresh.samba&hl=en

Comment: Depends on user experience, @Logos -- sure I could have mentioned Samba, WebDAV, FileSync apps, and a lot more. For completeness, I could of course include them.

Comment: yup, depends on user experience. Mine is good. So I mentioned it :)

Comment: Great! So it holds a variant for everybody now :)

Comment: Is there a wireless solution **without** a wifi hotspot/WIFI access-point ? i.e. I would be interested a direct wifi connexion between pc and android device

Comment: @Basj probably not without root (I'm not aware of any WiFi-Direct solution for PCs; so that would require ad-hoc networking, which Android doesn't support on its own).

Comment: Oh, for completeness: Seems like I forgot to mention `adb pull` – but people having ADB installed probably don't need that reminder anyway :)