# How to run SSH/SFTP server for multiple user logins with password authentication on Android?

Tags: linux, ssh, remote-access, file-sharing

I want to run an SSH server on my Android phone so that my clients (varying between 10 to 20) can easily and securely share data with me when I'm on the go, without using any third-party hosting services like email, file sharing, etc. Every user should have their own directory (enforced using SFTP's chroot) and he/she should be able to log in using his/her own password (not the key file) I provide them, optionally sharing credentials with other users if one needs to.

I didn't find any such flexible solution, especially FOSS. So I built `sshd` program from [openssh source code](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable), using `gcc-linux-aarch64` cross compiler on Ubuntu. However, when I execute it on my phone, it throws an error:

```
~# sshd -d
Privilege Separation user sshd does not exist
```

How can I add `sshd` and other users on Android? My phone is rooted.

**PS:** I'm jotting down an answer to my own question of what limitations I faced and how I have been achieving this for the past few years. Any other method - particularly a non-root solution through GUI for ease of a common user - would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

***Note:***

- *Make sure your phone is accessible from internet as explained [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/205807/218526).*
- *You need a rooted device.*

Android phones nowadays aren't those old low-end devices, they can run a full-featured SSH server happily. And it's an easy recipe:

- Get fully static `sshd` binary for your phone's architecture. See details below.
- Create `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/shadow`. To add a new user with password like we do on a Linux OS:

  ```
  ~# mount -o rw,remount /system; mount -o rw,remount /
  ~# touch /etc/passwd /etc/shadow
  ~# busybox adduser -D -H -h /dev/null -s /system/bin/false -u 900 sshd
  ~# busybox adduser -D -H -h /home/user1 -s /system/bin/sh -u 901 user1
  ~# toybox passwd user1
  ~# mkdir -p /data/home/user1/Documents /home /sdcard/home /etc/ssh
  ~# mount -o bind /data/home /home
  ~# mount -o bind /data/home /mnt/runtime/default/emulated/0/home
  ~# chmod 0750 /data/home/user1; chown 0.901 /data/home/user1
  ```

  First `bind` mount is required because otherwise SFTP's `chroot` won't work with `/data`'s [bad ownership](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/openssh/+/509874ae3aa741f380bc5d2445788325e5092bd0/auth.c#460). Second is to easily access shared files from `/sdcard/home`. To set non-root permissions on `/sdcard/home`, use [bindfs](https://bindfs.org/) instead.
  `sshd` user is for [Privilege Separation](https://bindfs.org/). `user1` is our first user that'll be able to login through SSH. In the same way more users can be added.
- Add required configurations to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` (defaults suffice in most cases):

  ```
  UsePAM no
  PasswordAuthentication yes
  Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
  Match User user1
    ChrootDirectory /home/user1
  ```
- Run SSH server, may use `logwrapper` to get log in `logcat`:

  ```
  ~# ssh-keygen -A    # generate host keys on first use
  ~# /system/bin/sshd -4 -E /sdcard/home/.sshd.log
  ```

  Now you can access server through SFTP / SSHFS. `SSHD` can also be run as an `init` service that's handled by Android's `init`. See [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/213623/218526) for explanation.

---

### DETAILS:

SSH server lets you login remotely after proper authentication. Additionally it serves sharing of files and many other resource sharing securely. But there is no concept of `Linux console login` on Android <sup>([1](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/209053/218526))</sup> because it boots directly to GUI. However it makes use of Discretionary Access Control (DAC) of Linux kernel which is based on UIDs / GIDs and permission mode. Every installed app is considers as a *NIX user and is assigned a unique UID at install time. See [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/208982/218526) for more details on this.

**HOW USER LOGIN AND AUTHENTICATION WORK:**

Traditionally `/etc/passwd` contained *username vs. UID/GID* mapping, while *supplementary GIDs* were added to `/etc/group`. Password was also added to `/etc/passwd` which was later moved to `/etc/shadow` with the introduction of [shadow password suite](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/~bdubbs/lfs-museum/3.0/LFS-BOOK-3.0-HTML/aa-shadow.html). Similarly `/etc/gshadow` contains *Secure Group Account Information*. These files are read by privilege granting programs such as `login`, `su`, `sshd` etc. and managed by administering programs such as `passwd` and `useradd`.

Most of these programs are part of [shadow](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/development/chapter06/shadow.html#contents-shadow) and [util-linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Util-linux) package and their behavior is controlled by defining a number of configuration items in `/etc/login.defs`, for instance logging of different events, password expiry, environment variables etc. Also there are many files that are required or updated by these utilities, including `nologin`, `default/useradd`, `adduser.conf`, `skel/`, `shells`, `subuid`, `subgid`, `limits` files under `/etc/`, `/var/log/faillog`, `/var/log/lastlog`, `/var/run/utmp`, `/var/run/wtmp` and possibly others.

To centralize the functionality of these privilege granting and administering programs, a more sophisticated authentication mechanism [PAM](http://www.linux-pam.org/Linux-PAM-html/sag-introduction.html) was introduced. Instead of directly handling the user login and authentication stuff, programs link to PAM libraries (called [modules](http://homedir.jct.ac.il/~roman/linux/pam/pam-list.html)) which in turn respond accordingly depending on its configuration files mainly under `/etc/pam.d` and `/etc/security`.

Other than PAM, a complicated name resolution mechanism [NSS](http://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/nss.5.html) also (a set of [modules](http://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/nsswitch.conf.5.html)) exists on Linux distros which controls - among many other things - how `passwd`, `group`, and `shadow` databases are read depending on its configuration file `/etc/nsswitch.conf`. Both PAM and NSS can be configured to use remote database service like [LDAP](https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/LDAP-HOWTO/whatisldap.html) / [NIS](https://www.thkukuk.de/nis/). And then there are centralized caching daemons like [NSCD](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/8-nscd/) and [SSSD](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/175124/how-pam-nss-ssd-work-together-on-linux-os.html). Working together, they complete the puzzle of user logins (identification and authentication) on Linux.

**HOW TO SETUP LOGIN ENVIRONMENT ON ANDROID:**

None of the above described configuration files and libraries exist on Android because user logins don't happen at all. But the programs built with Linux's standard libc APIs require all these files and services - including PAM - on Android too, which is near to impossible. PAM can be disabled for `sshd` by setting `UsePAM no` in `sshd_config` so that it directly reads files `/etc/passwd`, `/etc/group` and `/etc/shadow`.

PAM be gone, still we need to provide a minimal environment that meets the least requirements of login process. `ssh` binary for instance, needs `/etc/passwd` to exist necessarily because it sets `$HOME` from there to read `known_hosts`, `config` and `id_* key`. Also if host is a domain name and not an IP address, `/etc/resolv.conf` must exist with `nameserver` for DNS to work. It's a different story explained [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/205740/218526).

So we need to create the relevant files on Android manually. Or use the [non-PAM](https://github.com/shadow-maint/shadow/blob/bb3f810611ca254b07f0af4597b2735b6d1c4be1/configure.ac#L580) counterparts of `shadow-utils` such as `useradd` and `passwd` to update these files. We can get a minimal set of these utilities on Android, e.g. with busybox or toybox.

**RUNNING LINUX PROGRAMS ON ANDROID:**

Ideally you should write / modify the source code of a program in accordance with Android environment and then build dynamic binaries / libraries using Android's NDK and Bionic libc. But due to differences among Linux distros and Android such as in filesystem hierarchy, kernel configuration, implementation of libc and other libraries <sup>([2](https://github.com/libevent/libevent/blob/master/select.c#L63))</sup>, code written for Linux distros need heavy modification on Android, otherwise don't mind [failed attempts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15796291/how-to-cross-compile-openssh-for-arm). In case of `openssh`, see the list of modification patches in [AOSP](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/openssh/+log/refs/heads/master) and on [Termux](https://github.com/termux/termux-packages/tree/master/packages/openssh). Two of these patches are ***no password authentication*** <sup>([3](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/openssh/+/509874ae3aa741f380bc5d2445788325e5092bd0/auth2-passwd.c#70))</sup> and ***no multiple users*** <sup>([4](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/openssh/+/95194cb22a6b7ff71a91517c2a98d7bebef87e8f/auth.c#632), [5](https://github.com/termux/termux-packages/blob/master/packages/openssh/auth.c.patch#L9))</sup>. Former was worked around on Termux by introducing new APIs in *termux-auth* <sup>([6](https://github.com/termux/termux-packages/blob/master/packages/openssh/auth.c.patch#L9), [7](https://github.com/termux/termux-auth))</sup>, but the later can't be achieved without setting up login environment on Android.

Other options is to build fully static binary with Linux's libc such as `glibc`, `musl` or `uClibc`. While it's easy to statically build small libraries, libc itself links to many other libraries. In case of [glibc](http://tldp.org/LDP/lfs/5.0/html/appendixa/glibc.html), all of them can't be built statically, such as dynamically-loaded modules. I'm not sure how effective `--enable-static-nss` is, but, e.g. `gconv` can't be linked statically <sup>([8](https://www.systutorials.com/5217/how-to-statically-link-c-and-c-programs-on-linux-with-gcc/))</sup>. So `sshd` binary must not be built with `glibc`, otherwise it won't work without NSS modules.
Also set Privilege Separation Path to some existing directory like `/data/local/tmp` and disable any other unnecessary features like `utmp`, `wtmp`, `lastlog` etc. Or you would need to create `/var` directory in `rootfs`.

**FURTHER READING:**

- [Basic explanation on NSS , LDAP and PAM](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/166140/262728)
- [How To Add Linux User on Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/201285/218526)
- [Linux vs. Android](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=75905973&postcount=2)
- [How to connect two phones via SSH?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/214811/218526)