# How to connect to a SSH server from Android client?

Tags: command-line, ssh

I can install and run an SSH server on my Android 6.0 phone (Banana SSH server), and I can run an SSH client on it (Termius), so how do I invoke the client from on the command line that the server provides?  I type `ssh` and it's not a recognized command.  I want to use the phone to link through to other servers.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to install server in order to use client. Install `openssh` package on [Termux](https://termux.com/), that has both; server and client. To connect to a server, do: `ssh <user>@<server-IP>`. Mention port with `-p` option if different than default (`22`), such as Termux server uses <strike>2222</strike> `8022` (corrected by @Steve).

Or if you want to stick to GUI, you can go for Termius or ConnectBot etc.

In order to run SSH server, just execute `sshd` from Termux, but that gets killed with app. Or for a more complicated setup see: [How to run SSH/SFTP server for multiple user logins with password authentication on Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/209919/218526)