# rooted device: how to run SSH server persistent even on reboot

Tags: ssh, open-source, bash, rsync

I (linux user but not an expert) just moved from iOS to android, my device is rooted (Samsung s9) and I want a ssh server running all the time on my android device (I prefer openssh over dropbear) since I have to rsync files. I also prefer linux style commands e.g., systemctl restart service or similar.

I noticed that one can use Termux but it is an emulator, it won't work upon reboot.
[MagiskSSH](https://github.com/D4rCM4rC/MagiskSSH/tree/v0.1) seems to be interesting. Also noticed this [thread](https://forum.xda-developers.com/crossdevice-dev/sony/openssh-bash-t3716882) where pre-built Native OpenSSH and BASH are shared. Also, I am not sure if they run upon reboot). [Buildroot](https://buildroot.uclibc.org) has also been suggested to compile the package on my own (but my knowledge is limited on this topic).

On the top of this, I have to install rsync and bash.

So, how do I run ssh server persistent (works on reboot)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run SSH/SFTP server for multiple user logins with password authentication on Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/209918/how-to-run-ssh-sftp-server-for-multiple-user-logins-with-password-authentication)

Comment: For persistence, run it as an [init service](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/213623/218526). So do I, but only when I'm connected to some network. Also see [Termux:Boot](https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Termux:Boot) if you want to stick with GUI apps.