# Android boot.img installing BusyBox with Dropbear

Tags: boot, ssh

I have installed TWRP on my device, extracted boot.img. 
Initially I just wanted to build Dropbear for Android and make it run from boot.img.

I don't need any app to have root access.
What I would like is to have Dropbear running root and be able to SSH into it having root access.
I'm not experienced with BusyBox. I used a little bit of OpenWrt with BusyBox 1.28, but seriously don't know it much.
What I need is to have root SSH access to be able to configure some things. Be able to do some configuration with Ansible Playbooks for the phone would be nice addition.
I'd like to be able install certain program packages, the similar way I did in Openwrt I recently installed cURL package. I need to write some scripts which will be executed as jobs, something like cronjobs.
So the question is, do I need BusyBox for that or just build Dropbear? 
It seems BusyBox would be very nice thing in my case.

Comment: For scheduled jobs run `busybox crond`. On Android 10+ `init` services can be run as scheduled jobs with `restart_period` option, so you don't need a third party tool. // If you need remote shell `adb` in WiFi mode may help but doesn't fulfill my needs. So I run a full OpenSSH server: [How to run SSH/SFTP server for multiple user logins with password authentication on Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/209919/218526)

Comment: @IrfanLatif I see you use busybox, have you just downloaded binary or build it yourself and run it on your android or you're using Magisk Core Mode Only which has busybox? Seems there's no need for me to use Magisk.

Comment: I have used different `busybox` builds but ATM I'm using my own (you can find it [here](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=81800269&postcount=585)). It's somewhat limited because for many tools I use static built binaries e.g. `coreutils`, `util-linux` etc.